# Peculiar Integral Calculation: $\int^1_{0} \bigg( \frac{x}{1-x} \bigg)^t x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: integration, beta-function

I am trying to take the following integral.

$$\int^1_{0} \bigg( \frac{x}{1-x} \bigg)^t x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \mathrm{dx}$$

where $a, b >0$.

I am at a point where I can only combine the factors so much, and I am at a stopping point. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to proceed possibly using the beta function?

Comment: While $\int u^{b-t-1}(1-u)^{a+t-1}\mathrm{d}u$ is in general intractable, it's nice if one or both powers are integers $\ge0$, or we integrate on $[0,\,1]$.

Comment: @J.G. yes, those are the bounds. I forgot to add them

Comment: You tagged the question beta function, so presumably you already know it's expressible in terms of the gamma function, which generalizes the factorial to non-integer values. Are you asking how to prove the formula with gamma functions? (Wikipedia answers that.) Otherwise, what specifically are you asking?

Comment: I want to know how to use the beta function in this case @runway44 - sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Your integral is $B(a+t,b-t)$. What do you mean by "use" the beta function? Use it how? To do what?

Comment: To solve the integral... @runway44

Comment: It's already solved, no? You write it in terms of gamma functions, it can't be simplified any further.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function)$$\int_0^1x^{a+t-1}(1-x)^{b-t-1}\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname{B}(a+t,\,b-t)=\frac{\Gamma(a+t)\Gamma(b-t)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$